# Generating signed APK fails on one build config

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-buildconfig

I am working on a project and had to generate a signed APK. It works perfect for one flavor and the debug of the other. It says Password verification failed on the release config of the config I am trying to build. What can this be?

Latest Android Studio.

Comment: please post your error (screenshot)....

Comment: It just says Password verification failed on red color?

Comment: Please provide snippet of your gradle code or some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Did this start with updating Android Studio? I have the same issue and changed from a signed APK to Android App Bundle, then used the Google Play App Signing. This doesn't fix the problem, but might be a workaround until you figure it out